# Diacritic signs for those letters that usually do not have them

Tags: unicode, character, custom-keyboard, msklc

I'm using MicroSoft Keyboard Layout Creator (v 1.4) to setup a layout for my keyboard in order to use the alphabet I create from different languages on the computer.

I'm almost done, but I would like to implement even the accents I use for the letters, but I can't find the characters with the diacritic sign I want because in the original languages those letters do not have that sign. I've seen on Wikipedia [Combining Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) that diacritic signs from Unicode could be put on any other Unicode character (like ZalgoText, that even has them stacked) but I don't know how to do.
So I need a way to make the characters I want and get their unicode codes to put in MSKLC.

I searched all over the web to find something that could create every possible combination of diacritic signs with the letters I want to put them on, but the only thing I've found were some editors that created text overmodified like Zalgo.

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Put the combining diacritic character after the character it modifies.

For example, Unicode character U+0302 (COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT) can be placed after other characters in Python below:

```py
print('A\u0302B\u0302C\u0302a\u0302b\u0302c\u0302')
```

Output:

```
ÂB̂Ĉâb̂ĉ
```

Rendering of the output correctly relies on the display engine used.  It should render correctly above in a browser (Chrome: [image: output]), but looks like the following at the Windows command prompt: [image: For example]

You can find the Unicode combining characters in the [Unicode Code Charts](https://www.unicode.org/charts), such as
[Combining Diacritical Marks](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

With most keyboard layouts created using MSKLC, keyboards tend to use precomposed characters rather than base character and combining diacritic. Vietnamese tones, tended to be the exception. Deadkeys onl supported a single generated character, so it wasn't possible to add combining sequences ot an existing deadkey sequence.

The easiest solution, if you have based your layout on an existing system layout, is to remove the deadkeys, and the logic associated with the deadkeys. Then set the key to type the equivalent combining diacritic.